# react navigation 5: how to remove bottom border when using a custom header component

Tags: react-native, header, expo, react-navigation-v5

I'm using react-navigation v5 in my app. I would like to use a **custom header component**. But no matter what I do, I can't get rid of the bottom border on ios and android. I've looked at similar stackoverflow issues. It seems that the solutions proposed don't work when a custom header component is used instead of the built-in header component.

Here is how I setup my navigation component:

```
const MainStack = createStackNavigator();

export const MainNavigator = () => (
  <MainStack.Navigator
     screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: {
        elevation: 0,
        shadowOpacity: 0,  
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
      },
      header: CustomHeader,
    }}
  >
    <MainStack.Screen name="home-screen" component={HomeScreen} />
  </MainStack.Navigator>
)
```

And here is my CustomHeader component:

```
export const CustomHeader = () => (
 <View style={styles.header})>
   <Text>My App</Text>
</View>
);
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
     position: 'absolute',
     left: 0,
     right: 0,
     top: 0,
  }
})
```

I looked at countless stackoverflow issues where most advise to apply the style I just did above: elevation = 0 (android), shadow-opacity: 0 (ios) with no result. It seems that this technique does not work when a custom header is used.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can add `shadowColor: 'transparent'` in headerStyle of navigation stack

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this issue by adding null value to header in navigationOptions prop in your main navigator like this

```
header:null
```

and then call your header component inside each screen.

Comment: That's the path I took unfortunately. But I think it is counter-productive. The fact that you supply a custom header means you want to take over control, most of time to style things differently. But your custom style is override, defeating the purpose of a custom header.

Also implementing a header inside your views forces you to repeat much of the navbar logic e.g show/hide back button.

But I guess there is no other way...